# Unable to read request body of HttpServletRequest multiple times in case of multipart/form-data

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, content-type, servlet-filters

I know there are plenty of examples to read request body multiple times, I have gone through alot but couldn't find the solution to my problem.

So, in my case i have a spring-boot project which uploads file to Amazon s3. I want to read the request body of whatever file i am uploading inside the servlet-filter.

I tried the below wrappers

1. https://github.com/isapir/servlet-filter-utils
2. [ContentCachingRequestWrapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.java)
3. https://gitlab.com/jamietanna/multiple-read-servlet/-/blob/master/src/main/java/me/jvt/multireadservlet/MultiReadHttpServletRequest.java

a) For the first and second one, i get empty request body in case of multipart/form-data.

b) For the second one if i call `requestWrapper.getParameterMap()` for caching, i still get empty request body.

c) For the first one if i call `requestWrapper.getParameterMap()` for caching, i get the request body but request doesn't execute and results in Bad Request.

Below is the exception:

`Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]`

d) For the third case also, i get the same above exception in case of multipart/form-data, normally it works fine (in case of other requests).

Edit: *I have also gone through [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) articles [(1)](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/11/multipartfilter.html) & [(2)](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/12/uploading-files-in-servlet-30.html), but getting same exception.
I found that i have to implement my own `getPart(String part)` & `getPart()` in my custom requestWrapper in order to handle this multipart/form-data request.
I don't find any reference implementation for `getParts()` & `getPart(String part)`.*

I'm stuck, please help!!!